# Labeling each array in a collection of arrays using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

If I have a collection which contains arrays of objects, is it possible to label or add a key for each array with in the array? Example:

convert this:

```
var groups = [
              [{year:"1986", key2: "foo2"}, {year:"1986", key2:"blah"}],
              [{year:"1987", key2: "baz"}, {year:"1987", key2:"beek"}],
              [{year:"1988", key2: "baz"}, {year:"1988", key2:"beek"}]
             ]
```

To this:

```
var groups = [
              a:[{year:"1986", key2: "foo2"}, {year:"1986", key2:"blah"}],
              b:[{year:"1987", key2: "baz"}, {year:"1987", key2:"beek"}],
              c:[{year:"1988", key2: "baz"}, {year:"1988", key2:"beek"}]
             ]
```

My guess is something like this can only be possible if I turn the collection into some sort of object. Any thoughts?

Comment: no, you cannot do that, but you can use, 0,1,2 which are the indices... or put it an object, {} and use a, b, c

Comment: It's already an object and you can add properties with a map.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have them in an object to access them by a key. You can convert your groups to it with this.

```
function convertGroup (groups) {
    var new_group = {};
    var count = 1;

    for (var row in groups) {
        new_group[count] = groups[row]
        count++;
    }

    return new_group
}
```

It will output:

```
var groups = {
              1:[{year:"1986", key2: "foo2"}, {year:"1986", key2:"blah"}],
              2:[{year:"1987", key2: "baz"}, {year:"1987", key2:"beek"}],
              3:[{year:"1988", key2: "baz"}, {year:"1988", key2:"beek"}]
             }
//groups[1] = [{year:"1986", key2: "foo2"}, {year:"1986", key2:"blah"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

A JavaScript `Array` index must be an integer. If you want to give your values descriptive keys, you have to use an object or a `HashMap`.

The following code will return an object `{a: groups[0], b: groups[1], c: groups[2]}`:

```js
var groups = [
  [{year:"1986", key2: "foo2"}, {year:"1986", key2:"blah"}],
  [{year:"1987", key2: "baz"}, {year:"1987", key2:"beek"}],
  [{year:"1988", key2: "baz"}, {year:"1988", key2:"beek"}]
];

var labels = ["a", "b", "c"];

groups = groups.reduce((result, group, index) => {
  result[labels[index]] = group;
  return result;
}, {});

console.log(groups);
```